# nginx sometimes gets killed after reloading it using systemd

Tags: nginx

After upgrading my Ubuntu server to 20.04 from 18.04 the nginx started with strange behaviour. It dies **randomly** on `systemctl reload nginx` and complains that there is already process listening on given ports. Before I'm able to run portmap or something similar I'm already able to start nginx using `systemctl start nginx` with no problems so I think the problem is nginx is trying to bind to ports which are already taken by the old nginx being reloaded.

I haven't tried much because I'm lost. I've checked that the `/run/nginx.pid` contains correct pid. There is docker on my server so I thought maybe some container starts trying to bind 80 or 443 but no. The only mapped port for docker is 8090.

Versions:

```
nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

cat /etc/os-release 
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
...
```

Configuration files are valid:

```
nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

All ports nginx binds to are the same it complains about in the journal log:

```
cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/* | grep listen | uniq
listen 80 default_server;
listen 127.0.0.1:8080;
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
```

Do you have any idea why nginx would die on reload? What more can I check?

### Logs produced

#### `dmesg`

```
[31326.529427] traps: nginx[746] general protection fault ip:7f5f8cadc593 sp:7ffd350738d0 error:0 in libperl.so.5.30.0[7f5f8ca74000+166000]
[31408.549262] traps: nginx[26366] general protection fault ip:7efda22e8593 sp:7ffda51c0bd0 error:0 in libperl.so.5.30.0[7efda2280000+166000]
[32103.236557] nginx[26433]: segfault at 3d1 ip 00007efe600ce5c9 sp 00007ffead1b3210 error 4 in libperl.so.5.30.0[7efe60066000+166000]
[32103.236566] Code: 00 0f b6 40 30 49 c1 ed 03 49 29 c5 0f 84 17 01 00 00 48 8b 76 10 48 8b 52 10 4c 8d 3c fe 4c 8d 0c c2 84 c9 0f 84 c7 02 00 00 <49> 83 39 00 0f 85 ad 03 00 00 49 83 c1 08 49 83 ed 01 49 8d 74 1d
[32676.779937] nginx[31927]: segfault at 10 ip 00007f7550de2593 sp 00007ffce0bf4cd0 error 4 in libperl.so.5.30.0[7f7550d7a000+166000]
[32676.779952] Code: 48 89 43 10 48 83 c4 18 5b 5d 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 41 5f c3 0f 1f 40 00 0f b6 7f 30 48 c1 e8 03 48 29 f8 48 89 c3 74 89 48 8b 02 <4c> 8b 68 10 4d 85 ed 0f 84 28 01 00 00 0f b6 40 30 49 c1 ed 03 49
[33337.193774] traps: nginx[32415] general protection fault ip:7f195aa5e593 sp:7ffca566bad0 error:0 in libperl.so.5.30.0[7f195a9f6000+166000]
[40155.333210] nginx[39879]: segfault at 41 ip 00007fe42f53c593 sp 00007ffe812e18f0 error 4 in libperl.so.5.30.0[7fe42f4d4000+166000]
[40155.333219] Code: 48 89 43 10 48 83 c4 18 5b 5d 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 41 5f c3 0f 1f 40 00 0f b6 7f 30 48 c1 e8 03 48 29 f8 48 89 c3 74 89 48 8b 02 <4c> 8b 68 10 4d 85 ed 0f 84 28 01 00 00 0f b6 40 30 49 c1 ed 03 49
```

#### Journal

```
Oct 28 01:32:24 fooServer systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Oct 28 01:32:25 fooServer systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Oct 28 01:35:05 fooServer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
Oct 28 01:35:05 fooServer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 587 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.
Oct 28 01:35:05 fooServer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 2048 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.
Oct 28 01:35:05 fooServer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 2049 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.
Oct 28 01:35:05 fooServer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 2050 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.
Oct 28 01:35:05 fooServer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 2051 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.
Oct 28 01:35:05 fooServer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 2052 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.
Oct 28 01:35:05 fooServer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 2053 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.
Oct 28 01:35:05 fooServer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 2054 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.
Oct 28 01:35:05 fooServer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 2055 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.
Oct 28 01:35:05 fooServer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 587 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.
Oct 28 01:35:05 fooServer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 2048 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.
Oct 28 01:35:05 fooServer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 2049 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.
Oct 28 01:35:05 fooServer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 2050 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.
Oct 28 01:35:05 fooServer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 2051 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.
Oct 28 01:35:05 fooServer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 2052 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.
Oct 28 01:35:05 fooServer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 2053 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.
Oct 28 01:35:05 fooServer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 2054 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.
Oct 28 01:35:05 fooServer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 2055 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.
Oct 28 01:35:05 fooServer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Nov 02 05:32:05 fooServer systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Nov 02 05:32:05 fooServer nginx[415078]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:05 fooServer nginx[415078]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:05 fooServer nginx[415078]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:05 fooServer nginx[415078]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:05 fooServer nginx[415078]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 127.0.0.1:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:06 fooServer nginx[415078]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:06 fooServer nginx[415078]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:06 fooServer nginx[415078]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:06 fooServer nginx[415078]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:06 fooServer nginx[415078]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 127.0.0.1:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:06 fooServer nginx[415078]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:06 fooServer nginx[415078]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:06 fooServer nginx[415078]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:06 fooServer nginx[415078]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:06 fooServer nginx[415078]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 127.0.0.1:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:07 fooServer nginx[415078]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:07 fooServer nginx[415078]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:07 fooServer nginx[415078]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:07 fooServer nginx[415078]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:07 fooServer nginx[415078]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 127.0.0.1:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:07 fooServer nginx[415078]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:07 fooServer nginx[415078]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:07 fooServer nginx[415078]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:07 fooServer nginx[415078]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:07 fooServer nginx[415078]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 127.0.0.1:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:08 fooServer nginx[415078]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Nov 02 05:32:08 fooServer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 02 05:32:08 fooServer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 02 05:32:08 fooServer systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Nov 02 05:32:17 fooServer systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Nov 02 05:32:17 fooServer nginx[415100]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:17 fooServer nginx[415100]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:17 fooServer nginx[415100]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:17 fooServer nginx[415100]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:17 fooServer nginx[415100]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 127.0.0.1:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:17 fooServer nginx[415100]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:17 fooServer nginx[415100]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:17 fooServer nginx[415100]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:17 fooServer nginx[415100]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:17 fooServer nginx[415100]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 127.0.0.1:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:18 fooServer nginx[415100]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:18 fooServer nginx[415100]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:18 fooServer nginx[415100]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:18 fooServer nginx[415100]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:18 fooServer nginx[415100]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 127.0.0.1:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:18 fooServer nginx[415100]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:18 fooServer nginx[415100]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:18 fooServer nginx[415100]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:18 fooServer nginx[415100]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:18 fooServer nginx[415100]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 127.0.0.1:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:19 fooServer nginx[415100]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:19 fooServer nginx[415100]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:19 fooServer nginx[415100]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:19 fooServer nginx[415100]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:19 fooServer nginx[415100]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 127.0.0.1:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 02 05:32:19 fooServer nginx[415100]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Nov 02 05:32:19 fooServer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 02 05:32:19 fooServer systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 02 05:32:19 fooServer systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

#### `/var/log/nginx/error.log`:

```
2020/11/02 21:49:38 [info] 25842#25842: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:74
2020/11/02 21:49:40 [notice] 25846#25846: signal process started
2020/11/02 21:51:09 [notice] 26353#26353: signal process started
2020/11/02 21:51:19 [info] 26357#26357: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:74
2020/11/02 21:51:28 [info] 26364#26364: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:74
2020/11/02 21:52:31 [notice] 26406#26406: signal process started
2020/11/02 21:52:31 [notice] 26418#26418: signal process started
2020/11/02 21:52:38 [info] 26431#26431: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:74
2020/11/02 21:58:54 [info] 26584#26584: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:74
2020/11/02 21:58:57 [notice] 26589#26589: signal process started
2020/11/02 22:04:04 [info] 31847#31847: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:74
2020/11/02 22:04:06 [notice] 31855#31855: signal process started
2020/11/02 22:06:05 [info] 31925#31925: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:74
2020/11/02 22:12:39 [notice] 32321#32321: signal process started
2020/11/02 22:13:40 [notice] 32392#32392: signal process started
2020/11/02 22:13:53 [info] 32413#32413: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:74
2020/11/02 22:24:13 [notice] 39657#39657: signal process started
2020/11/02 22:24:40 [notice] 39837#39837: signal process started
2020/11/02 22:24:45 [info] 39870#39870: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:74
```

### Configuration

#### `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;
    client_max_body_size 1G;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:MozSSL:10m;  # about 40000 sessions
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    # curl https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/ffdhe2048.txt > /path/to/dhparam.pem
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

    # intermediate configuration
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

    # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (63072000 seconds)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000" always;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

#### most of my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf` looks like this one:

```
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name example.com;

  root /var/www/public;

  include fpm7.3.conf; # includes fastcgi_pass to php-fpm for *.php files

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;

  error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
}
```

Comment: @MichaelHampton the problem is already reported, thanks for showing me the `dmesg` command. I've updated the question with the `dmesg` log. bug report - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/perl/+bug/1897561/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've run into [a bug in perl 5.30](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/17154), the version used in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. The bug has been fixed upstream but that fix has not yet been backported to Ubuntu.

If you haven't got a need to run Perl code inside nginx (as most people do not) then you can uninstall the package `libnginx-mod-http-perl` and restart nginx to avoid the problem. This package was pulled in by the virtual package `nginx-extras` but most people don't actually run perl in the web server and so don't need it.

```
ubuntu@vmtest-ubuntu2004:~$ sudo apt purge libnginx-mod-http-perl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libhiredis0.14 libluajit-5.1-2 libluajit-5.1-common
  libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam libnginx-mod-http-cache-purge
  libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext libnginx-mod-http-echo
  libnginx-mod-http-fancyindex libnginx-mod-http-geoip
  libnginx-mod-http-geoip2 libnginx-mod-http-headers-more-filter
  libnginx-mod-http-lua libnginx-mod-http-ndk libnginx-mod-http-subs-filter
  libnginx-mod-http-uploadprogress libnginx-mod-http-upstream-fair
  libnginx-mod-nchan
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  nginx-core
Suggested packages:
  nginx-doc
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libnginx-mod-http-perl* nginx-extras*
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nginx-core
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 425 kB of archives.
After this operation, 173 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

---

```
ubuntu@vmtest-ubuntu2004:~$ sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Though in this specific case, nginx has probably gone zombie and you will have to restart the computer.

As shown above, removing it will replace `nginx-extras` with `nginx-core`, and mark all the extras packages as eligible for autoremoval, so if you actually need any of those packages you should mark them as installed before autoremoving.

```
ubuntu@vmtest-ubuntu2004:~$ sudo apt-mark install libnginx-mod-http-geoip2
Selected libnginx-mod-http-geoip2 for installation.
```

You can also [follow the issue on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/perl/+bug/1897561/).

Comment: I was wondering why only one server was affected. This one is running since release of 18.04 and I got used to install `nginx-extras` because it was standard at company I worked at. All other servers I manage have been set later and use`nginx` package. I've swapped `nginx-extras` for `nginx` and reload works now!

Comment: I knew it was a problem with 20.04 LTS. I had this problem as well and it never occurred in my life before I tried to run 20.04lts. Shame that this happens tho, lts suppose to be stable AFAIK.

Comment: @sed What should worry you is that the ubuntu maintainers are just sitting there and doing nothing about it despite having a patch available that they could backport.

Comment: Does anyone know the easiest way to replace this with version 5.30.2 or whichever is the latest 5.30.x version? Do I have to create my own, unofficial libnginx-mod-http-perl?

Answer (score 2):

If removing `libnginx-mod-http-perl` is not an option for you the next best workaround is to configure systemd to auto-restart nginx on failure.

This is rather simple to accomplish:

Create directory `/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/`

Create file `/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/override.conf` with the following contents:

```
[Unit]
StartLimitIntervalSec=500
StartLimitBurst=5

[Service]
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
```

Run `systemctl daemon-reload`

Restart nginx `systemctl restart nginx.service`

In my experience Nginx usually crashes after the 2nd reload. If that happens now systemd will start Nginx five seconds after it fails.

You can customize the settings to your needs:

`StartLimitBurst` defines how many times in a row systemd will attempt to start Nginx after it fails.
`StartLimitIntervalSec` defines how much time must pass before it will try restarting again.
`RestartSec` defines how long to wait after Nginx fails before trying to start it.

Answer (score 0):

If removing `libnginx-mod-http-perl` is not an option for you the next best workaround is to disable perl module.

```
mkdir /etc/nginx/_modules-disabled
mv /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-perl.conf /etc/nginx/_modules-disabled/
```

And restart `nginx` gracefully

```
mkdir /root/tools/
touch /root/tools/nginx_restart.sh
chmod +x /root/tools/nginx_restart.sh
nano /root/tools/nginx_restart.sh
```

```
#!/bin/bash

for command in quit stop; do
  if ps aux | grep -v 'grep ' | grep -v "${0}" | grep -q nginx; then
    echo;
    echo "nginx -s $command";
    nginx -s $command;
    for (( i=1 ; i <= 300 ; i=((i+1)) )); do
      sleep 1;
      echo -n ".";
      if ! ps aux | grep -v 'grep ' | grep -v "${0}" | grep -q nginx; then
        break 2;
      fi;
    done;
  fi;
done;

echo;
sleep 1;

if ! ps aux | grep -v 'grep ' | grep -v "${0}" | grep -q nginx; then
  /etc/init.d/nginx start;
  sleep 1;
fi;

/etc/init.d/nginx status;
```

```
/root/tools/nginx_restart.sh
```